# genetic code and zombies!

Tags: matlab

In an alien world, the genetic codes of the creatures are in base-4 system(quartenary). The pairs "13" and "22" are considered as genetic disorders. With a genetic code of lenght n, if there are at least n/4 disorders, the creature becomes a zombie!! For example with n=5, the creature with genetic code 01321 has the disorder, but not a zombie while the creature with genetic code 22132 is a zombie( because he has two disorders which is >n/4).

Now I need to write a MATLAB program and get a value n from the user, which is easy, and display the number of creatures and how many of them are zombies

Here is what i've written so far, I can't figure out how to determine the creatures with has genetic codes of a zombie. I'd really appreciate your ideas and help.Thank you

```
n=input('Enter the length of the genetic sequence: ');
while (n<4) || (mod(n,1))~=0
disp('Invalid input!')
n=input('Enter the length of the genetic sequence: ');
end
nOfCreatures=4^n;
count=0;
for i=0:nOfCreatures
k=dec2base(i,4);
end
fprintf('There are %g creatures and %g of them are zombies.\n',nOfCreatures,count);
```

Comment: How many disorders does "222" count as?

Comment: It counts as 2 disorders

Answer (score 2):

I recommended you in my comment to try REGEXP function. But actually STRFIND would suite much better if you want to count overlaps, like count '222' as 2 disorders.

So you need something like this:

```
k=dec2base(i,4,n); %# use n to include trailing 0s, just for other possible types of disorders
m = [strfind(k,'13') strfind(k,'22')];
if numel(m) > n/4
    count = count+1;
end
```

In addition, you can do `n=0` as the first line instead of duplicating the input line.
And correct for-loop to end at `nOfCreatures-1`.

**EDIT**

For the bonus a vectorized solution:

```
nOfCreatures=4^n;
k=cellstr(dec2base(0:nOfCreatures-1,4,n));
m = cellfun(@numel,strfind(k,'13')) + cellfun(@numel,strfind(k,'22'));
count = sum(m > n/4);
fprintf('There are %g creatures and %g of them are zombies.\n',nOfCreatures,count);
```

Comment: This is a much more elegant solution than mine

Answer (score 0):

```
error = 0
    for i<n.len:
        if n[i] == 1:
           if n[i+1] == 3:
              error = error + 1
        if n[i] == 2:
           if n[i+1] == 2:
              error = error + 1
if error >= n/4
     zombie = true
```

That is the general idea in psuedo code.

Here is a link that might help you convert this into real code: [String Handling](http://www.matlabcorner.com/matlab-tutorial-3-strings-in-matlab/)